# Make a command for several variables

Tags: r

I have five different parameters that I would like to join in `list_of_countries` (= c() ) so when I run the the last code it approaches all variables.

In other words, a refined way of `country_df$US`, `country_df$Canada` etc...

```
list_of_countries
US
Canada
France
Australia
Japan
```

```
tibble(country_df$list_of_countries)
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to create a data.frame or a tibble?

```r
list_of_countries<-scan(text='
US
Canada
France
Australia
Japan',what=character())

country_df <- data.frame(list_of_countries)
country_df
#>   list_of_countries
#> 1                US
#> 2            Canada
#> 3            France
#> 4         Australia
#> 5             Japan

country_df <- tibble::tibble(list_of_countries)
country_df
#> # A tibble: 5 × 1
#>   list_of_countries
#>   <chr>            
#> 1 US               
#> 2 Canada           
#> 3 France           
#> 4 Australia        
#> 5 Japan
```

<sup>Created on 2022-08-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>